# What's the easiest & cheapest way to determine if request.user was authenticated using social?

Tags: python-social-auth

Do I need to add my own pipeline function to add something to the request object, or is there already some flag or indicator on the request object? I couldn't find one. Thanks.

Comment: `python-social-auth` doesn't add any flag, you can check the session for `social_auth_last_login_backend` which will hold the last social backend used (`google-oauth2`, `facebook`, etc). Or if using Django, you could check for `request.session[SESSION_KEY]` and `request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY]` which should point to a backend in `python-social-auth`, (those variables can be imported from `django.contrib.auth`).

Comment: Thanks @omab. session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] worked for me. I wasn't so sure about using social_auth_last_login_backend, because it seems that might persist even after logout?

Comment: ``logout`` will clean your session, so no, it won't be persisted.